# Why are there two Cordova www folders?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm a beginner in PhoneGap and I'm trying to understand something about the www folders.
I created a project with only an iOS platform.

I saw that there are two www folders:

- www in the root folder of the project
- www in the `platform/ios/` folder

How do I use both of them? Am I supposed to only use only one of them?
What about sharing the HTML/JS/CSS code with other platforms?

Answer (score 11):

- The `www` folder in the root folder of the project contains the **global files for all platforms**. This is the folder that you should edit.
- The `www` folder in `platforms/ios` is solely for the iOS platform. This folder is built from the global `www` folder **when you run `cordova build`**. You should not edit this folder directly - if you wish to customise a specific platform, see the [Customise Each Platform](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_customize_each_platform) section of the Cordova CLI documentation.

If you had more platforms (`cordova platform add <platform>`), then those platforms would also have their `www` folders built from the global `www` folder when you run `cordova build [platform]`.

Comment: I understand. But why, when you create a PhoneGap project, it's the www platform folder which is in the project ?

Comment: @SébastienPolytech' Do you mean why is the project built from the `www` folder in `platforms/ios` in Xcode? This is because different platforms have different ways of doing things and need different `www` folders with different JS and other files.

Comment: So what files are common to all the platforms ?

Comment: @SébastienPolytech' The files in the `www` folder at the root of your project are common to all platforms. The files in the `platforms/<platform>/www` folder are for a single platform (however you should not edit this folder directly - see my answer above).

Comment: Back to OP's first comment, the XCode project the CLI creates has a www folder reference to platofrm-www.  Yes, it is clear that platform-www is the one that is run and that it is generated so you shouldn't edit it.  But this means you cannot use XCode to edit any of the files you see.  Why not have the project reference the core www and then have a build step perform "cordova build" to get them in the right place?  Right now XCode is useless as an editor as it edits the wrong files, so on the flipside why not have "cordova build" run XCode through the command line?

Comment: I am new to PhoneGap too and totally agree with CBGraham.  The approach that phone gap uses renders XCOde useless as a tool for editing the files in the root www folder.  How are we supposed to edit the content in the root www folder?

Comment: And the same happens for Visual Studio, too. In Cordova generated Visual Studio project the www folder is linked to the platform/wp8/www which is so wrong for newbies. It seems, I cannot exclude it from my Visual Studio project because then it might fail to package the assets for Windows Phone, but I'll try to hide it and  see what happens.

Comment: @Tom As good as Xcode is, it's not a HTML/CSS/JS IDE. I suggest using a separate IDE/editor for the www folder, such as WebStorm.

Answer (score -2):

Check this demo project you got idea from it.

https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-demo-app

Comment: @Sabastien did you get some help from this or i should explain some more. :P

Comment: @Umesh Lakhani : the project doesn't compile because there are missing classes.

Comment: @Deepika Lalra, yes if you have explanations to give about the www folder and the project architecture, I'm listening with attention :D

Comment: See this is working code i have tested in my device   https://github.com/teusinkorg/jpHolo

Comment: You are not answering to my question !

Comment: @SébastienPolytech' there you should a www folder in your project(not that www in the platform/ios folder). You should place your files in only this folder. that's it.

Comment: @SébastienPolytech' i have made a project in phonegap with ios. and i vae faced many issues. if you want help or face any difficulty, if possible, i'll try my best to solve them with you.