# Which www directory to use to edit phonegap html/js files?

Tags: cordova

Which www directory should I edit? The one in the root of the PhoneGap project or the one under platforms/ios?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012234/phonegap-www-folder?rq=1